# Firestore: Do I have to use (FIR)Timestamp instead of (NS)Date

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore recently started to print a warning in the console that I'd have to use `areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true` on `FIRFirestoreSettings`.
At the same time I have to review and update the use of dates by replacing them with timestamps.

For my purpose the higher precision of FIRTimestamps is not required. Furthermore I would like to keep using (NS)Date in my models in order to avoid the firebase dependency within the models.

Is there a way I can keep using (NS)Dates in my `Codable` models without having to implement a custom decoder/ encoder when `areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled` is enabled?

Comment: Also having this problem. One thing I am concerned about is compatibility with existing databases that are using the Date format. If we change to Timestamp are we going to have to migrate everyone over to Timestamp etc.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Not able to understand how to make the change.